# jQuery mobile button style is lost on localization

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, i18next

I'm working on [jquerymobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) project using localization library [i18Next](http://i18next.com/).

HTML code:

```
<div id="messageboxPage" data-role="page" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a"></div>
    <div id="messagePage" data-role="content" data-theme="a">
        <div class="barContainer" id="barContainer">
            <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-b  ui-btn-corner-all" style=" margin-top: 40px; padding-left: 0px;padding-right:10px; ">
                <div style="float: left;  width: 30%;"> <a href="#" id="aNo" onclick="SetActive('aNo')" class="LnkButton" data-theme="a" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">Cancel</a> 
                </div>
                <div style="float: left;   width: 30%;padding-left: 6%; padding-right: 2%;"> <a href="#" id="aAccept" onclick="Supprimer();" data-theme="a" class="LnkButton" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">Delete</a> 
                </div>
                <div style="float: right; width: 30%;"> <a href="#" id="aReply" onclick="Reply();" data-theme="a" class="LnkButton" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">Reply</a> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js code

```
 window.opts = {
     lng: 'fr',
     getAsync: true,
     // fallbackLng: 'en',
     ns: {
         namespaces: ['ns.controls'],
         defaultNs: 'ns.controls'
     },
     useLocalStorage: false,
     debug: true
 };
 $.i18n.init(opts).done(function () {
     alert('i18n init function');
     $('#aNo').text("No Merci!");
     $('#aAccept').text("Supprimer");
     $('#aReply').text("Respondre");
     $('#messageboxPage').trigger('pagecreate');
 });

 $(document).ready(function () {
     alert('messagebox document ready');
 });
```

Now the problem is the text is changed, but the button style is lost. The second problem is setting text with labels; I have tried page create trigger, but it's not working. What do you suggest?

Here is a working [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skhurams/PJ46b/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the text of a button you have to modify the text of the `.ui-btn-text` element, much better than the `span > span` thing:

```
$('#aNo .ui-btn-text').text("No Merci!");
$('#aAccept .ui-btn-text').text("Supprimer");
$('#aReply .ui-btn-text').text("Respondre");
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PJ46b/16/)

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
$.i18n.init(opts).done(function () {
     alert('i18n init function');
     var message_type = 0;
     if (message_type == "0") {
         alert('from 0');
         $('#lblTo').text("from 0");
     } else if (message_type == "1") {
         alert('to 1');
         $('#lblTo').text("to 1");
     } else if (message_type == "2") {
         alert('from 2');
         $('#lblTo').text("from 2");
     }

     $('lblDate').text($.t('Messagebox.lblDate'));
     $('lblSubject').text($.t('Messagebox.lblSubject'));


     //////////////////////////this is where i was wrong
     $('#aNo > span > span').text("No Merci!");
     $('#aAccept > span > span').text("Supprimer");
     $('#aReply > span > span').text("Respondre");
     ///////////////////////////

     $('#messageboxPage').trigger('pagecreate');
 });
```